# Spring Boot Security: How to run authentication filter before CSRF in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, csrf, spring-security-rest

I am always getting unauthorize on Login.

On Login i need to authenticate user as well as generate CSRF token based on JWT token generated from user credentials.

I have CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter but i need to pass JWT generated after sucessfull authentication. My current code always execute CsrfFilterfirst and after that run authentication thing.

So Authentication First and then CsrfCookieGeneraterFilter.

Could anyone guide how to achieve using following builder (I am quite new to this Spring security thing implementation)

Following is code i am trying:

```
httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()            
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf()     
            .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(csrfRequestMatcher)
            .csrfTokenRepository(customCsrfTokenRepository)
            .and()            
            .cors()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(this.jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint);



       httpSecurity.addFilterAt(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(customCsrfTokenRepository), CsrfFilter.class);
       httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
```

Comment: I think that order of "ands" matters in this case. Try to swap authentication part with csrf part.

Comment: @PiotrKorlaga: Actually i do not understand. Kindly give snippet what you are trying to convey.

Comment: I meant that: https://gist.github.com/piotrkorlaga/4103f4b13f71549f3af33514f7b9285c